when I add a record in studio in settings one to one relation using reference Id
model Doctor {
id              String            @id @default(cuid())
field           String
memberId        String            @unique
member          Member            @relation(fields: [memberId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
userId          String            @unique
user            User              @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
clinicUserId    String
clinic          Clinic            @relation(fields: [clinicUserId], references: [userId], onDelete: Cascade)
appointmentSlot AppointmentSlot[]
shift           Shift[]
doctorSetting   DoctorSetting?
}
model DoctorSetting {
id                                String   @id @default(cuid())
allowMessagesFromUnbookedPatients Boolean  @default(true)
backgroundColor                   String?
blackList                         String[]
DAYS_TO_AUTO_COMPLETE_BOOKING     Int      @default(3)
doctorId                          String   @unique  // Changed from doctorUserId to doctorId
doctor                            Doctor   @relation(fields: [doctorId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)  // Changed to reference Doctor.id
}
I get error like this when I add a record in prisma studio  in settings
Tried to add record in Doctor Setting I get the above image shown error , and If I use userId in reference it works perfectly fine. I just dont understand why this error is shown when i use Id as reference
